# Asset pipeline and storing stylesheets in the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to link 2 SCSS files located in the public folder to a html.erb view. I've tried the following methods with no luck...

Attempt 1:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'new_public_style', media: 'all'%>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'publicStyles', media: 'all'%>
```

Attempt 2:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="new_public_style.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="publicStyles.scss">
```

When I place the stylesheets within app > assets > stylesheets folder everything works fine.... but the main goal is to store these files in the public folder. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious as to _why_ your goal is to store them in the public folder?

Comment: @ChrisPeters it's just for a style-guide page that will only be available in development mode.

Comment: Well, even if you got Rails to serve the SCSS files, it would not _process_ the SCSS files and generate the CSS that the browser wants. It must be in the asset pipeline to do that. You'll want to consider creating a separate asset manifest for your style guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you got Rails to serve the SCSS files, it would not *process* the SCSS files and generate the CSS that the browser wants. It must be in the asset pipeline to do that.

You'll want to consider creating a separate asset manifest for your style guide.